# Android app for a web application without an API

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to create an Android app for an existing web application which doesn't provide any API?

Webview just provides a crude view of the same web app in Android, but interface with webview looks crappy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking is very possible.  Just load up your URL in the webview and then redirect all clicks to go back to the same view.  There you have an embedded website into an application.

What do you mean by interface for WebView looks crappy?  You can make it look like anything native on the phone.

Comment: I have used webview for this same application, but the interface looks like web application opened in browser of a phone. I just want to show the important part of web application in android application like username, password and signin and signup buttons.

Comment: Add this to your Activity for the WebView in your AndroidManifest.xml and that should remove the browser look to the WebView.  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 1):

If you want your web page to have the look and feel of a native android app without creating the native app, you'll need to do so using javascript on your served page.  Take a look at http://jquerymobile.com/ which seems to do a lot of the leg work.  You can use that javascript and a little elbow grease to accomplish what you describe.